# Pass $(this) as argument of bind method - jQuery

Tags: jquery, arguments, bind

I would like to use `$(this)` as an argument in a bind function.

I want to bind the class of elements `someClass` to execute `someFunc` (an already-defined function) when `someEvent` occurs.

`someFunc` takes arguments, one being the element to act on, `element`. In this case, I want to act on whichever element with the class `someClass` the event occurs on.

So, I think I would use `$(this)`, just as an argument in the bind function:

```
$('.someClass').bind('someEvent', {element: $(this)}, someFunc);
```

But this does not seem to work despite making sense to me.

**How can I use `$(this)` or something that would produce the same results within a bind method?**

I would prefer not using something like the following:

```
$('.someClass').bind('someEvent', function() {
    someFunc($(this));
});
```

**EDIT: Trying it the way I do not prefer**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.menu-hover').bind('mouseenter', function() {

        hover_true($(this), '#1B4186');

    });

    $('.menu-hover').bind('mouseleave', function() {

        hover_false($(this), '#26519E');

    });

});

function hover_color(element, color) {

    $(element).css('background-color', color);

};
```

`hover_color` is simply meant to color a given `element` with a given `color`. It is not working (at all) and I have no idea why.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid using the way you would prefer not to.  It's the standard syntax for javascript callbacks.  Why would you not want to do it that way?

Comment: @MuppetGrinder I wanted the bind to be more compact. I'm new to jQuery, so I'm not familiar with the norms. I just tried what I didn't prefer, the less compressed way, and that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Have you checked what $(this) is when it is passed into the someFunct() function? can you edit your question to include what you have tried since initialy posting it and also the results of this?

Comment: @MuppetGrinder I added the problem I am encountering with the standard way you suggested.

Comment: I know it's not an answer, so I'm not posting it as such, but have you tried just using the callback alone rather than your personal function?  i.e.    $('.menu-hover).bind('mouseenter', function(){$( this ).css({'color':'#1B4186'})})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that during the bind call $(this) is still another context than it is at the time of the eventHandling. You are probably passing the document or something right now.

I don't see a way around using your least favored method, since only during the event handling itself the context is set to the element at hand.

Addition:
Actually maybe, since in your attempt 'someFunc' IS the eventHandler, you could actually simple use $(this) inside the declaration of someFunc, without any need for passing it as parameter at all.